# Error: $VARIABLE is not listed as a dependency in turbo.json

Tags: next.js, vercel, turborepo

I'm not able to solve an error which is mentioned in the title:

> Error: $VARIABLE is not listed as a dependency in turbo.json

When I run npm run build I get errors for 2 variables and not for all of them that's what is strange to me...

```
Error: $NEXT_STRIPE_SK is not listed as a dependency in turbo.json  turbo/no-undeclared-env-vars
Error: $NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PK is not listed as a dependency in turbo.json  turbo/no-undeclared-env-vars
```

turbo.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://turbo.build/schema.json",
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      "dependsOn": [
        "^build"
      ],
      "outputs": [
        "dist/**",
        ".next/**"
      ]
    },
    "order#build": {
      "dependsOn": [
        "^build"
      ],
      "env": [
        "NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PK",
        "NEXT_STRIPE_SK"
      ],
      "outputs": [
        ".next/**"
      ]
    },
    "lint": {
      "outputs": []
    },
    "dev": {
      "cache": false
    }
  },
  "globalEnv": [
    "NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL",
    "NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY",
    "SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE",
    "NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PK",
    "NEXT_STRIPE_SK"
  ],
  "globalDependencies": [
    "$NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL",
    "$NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY",
    "$SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE",
    "$NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PK",
    "$NEXT_STRIPE_SK"
  ]
},
```

This is my .env.local

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL=
NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY=
SUPABASE_SERVICE_ROLE=
NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PK=
NEXT_STRIPE_SK=
```

Answer (score 4):

As stated in [`turbo/no-undeclared-env-vars`](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin-turbo/docs/rules/no-undeclared-env-vars.md). You should be able to add the name of the env var to your `turbo.json`:

```js
// turbo.json

{
  "globalEnv": ["NEXT_STRIPE_SK, NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PK"],
  // ... rest of turbo.json
}
```

If you are using vscode and eslint, make sure to restart the eslint server through the command palette to update errors and warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [configuration](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/reference/configuration)

> A list of file globs for implicit global hash dependencies. The
> contents of these files will be included in the global hashing
> algorithm and affect the hashes of all tasks. This is useful for
> busting the cache based on .env files (not in Git) or any root level
> file that impacts workspace tasks (but are not represented in the
> traditional dependency graph (e.g. a root tsconfig.json,
> jest.config.js, .eslintrc, etc.)).

you should pass the name of the files to `globalDependencies`

```
"globalDependencies": [
    ".env", // contents will impact hashes of all tasks
    ".env.local",
    "tsconfig.json" // contents will impact hashes of all tasks
  ]
```

Comment: ye I've also tried to add .env.local which is on root of the project to globalDependencies block and it doesn't solve it either...

Comment: are you using `eslint`

Comment: Yes I have .eslintrc.js on the root of the dir, why?

Answer (score 1):

In NextJS, `process.env` is actually a dynamic structure that behaves differently from a traditional JavaScript object, despite having a similar interface. Because of this, NextJS can't always know whether a given key will exist on the `process.env` "object" at runtime. As a result, attempting to access a non-existent key using dot notation, like `process.env.someKey`, may cause a runtime error.

To avoid this issue, a better practice is to **use square bracket syntax** to attempt to extract the value from `process.env`. For example, `const value = process.env["someKey"]`. This syntax will not cause runtime errors if the key does not exist, and will instead return `undefined`.

**In summary,** try the square bracket syntax on environment variables and turbo.json should leave you alone. This is true in NextJS-turbo land, but I haven't checked other frameworks.

Source: I experienced this problem with a turbo project a few minutes ago while building a NextJS package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is wrong in that it asserts that square bracket syntax will not cause a runtime error but dot syntax will.  `process.env.someKey` *is the same thing as* `process.env["someKey"]`.  The only difference is you are tricking the eslint plugin for turbo into thinking everything is OK with the latter.  [All of the examples in Next's docs use dot notation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables)